# include layout android - causing issue with button background color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

I am having 1 layout which is common in all 3 tabs (Fragment) in my project. So what I did is I have created separate layout for that common structure and included the layout in all the fragments layout. The layout is basically having 4 buttons and on click of those buttons I am changing the background color of button and displaying data accordingly.

[image: This is the 1st tab in which its coming perfect.]

[image: This is the second tab where all the buttons are getting the blue color.]

Code  :-

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,
                container, false);
        mLvIncomingCalls = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv);

        mBtnDay = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDay);
        mBtnWeek = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
        mBtnMonth = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnMonth);
        mBtnAllTime = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnAllTime);

        mBtnDay.setOnClickListener(btnDayClickListener);
        mBtnWeek.setOnClickListener(btnWeekClickListener);
        mBtnMonth.setOnClickListener(btnMonthClickListener);
        mBtnAllTime.setOnClickListener(btnAllTimeClickListener);

        mBtnDay.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.holo_blue_light));

        return rootView;
    }
```

Now as seen in the snap shot, the problem is that in second tab by default all the button get the blue color. I am not getting why its getting blue for all buttons, as in all the fragment I am adding the above code which by default makes Day button color to blue only.

**Do I need to create separate layout for all?**

Anyone has any idea about it please kindly guide me.

Comment: Have you tried selector as background drawable for button?

Comment: No I have not tried selector because for all the buttons I have to create different different selectors. So i thought its better to handle it from code side. When some one click on a button I will change its color to blue and rest of will be grey.

Comment: How about you just ensure other buttons to be gray in onCreateView?

Comment: Because the default color in the Layout XML is set to GREY. So it must be grey. Do you mean to say that in onCreateView I need to set All colors again even though its set in XML file?

Comment: Have you tried using separate layouts if it makes any difference?

Comment: @Niko, you were right, I have to set the colors in onCreateView. I just did that and its working. But again, I have already set the default colors for the buttons in layout then why its not taking that color and why i need to set colors for all in onCreateView programatically again?

Comment: I believe the system is little bit messed up and recycles the background color drawable or something like that.

Comment: Strange behavior but wee need to live with that. Anyway thanks for the help @Niko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `onCreateView` you can set other button colors to gray. This way it should definitely not happen. The reason why it's happening is a mystery, I believe the system somehow recycles the `Drawable` incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Put onTabChangedListener

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (tabId.equals("first")) {
                // here you can set "setBackgroundColor"
            }else if (tabId.equals("second")) {
            ......
            ......
        }
    }
}
```

I think it will helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: If I implement it this way then every time it will set the default one. I don't think that it will work. But thanks for your suggestion.